# how to change 1.5hours to 1hour 30minutes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the time remaining from the two date-time and display it as a time format

```
        function roundDown(floating) {
         var rounded = Math.round(floating * 100) / 100;
         return rounded;
}

const start = new Date("2020-12-03T11:30:00Z").getTime() / (1000 * 3600);
const end = new Date("2020-12-03T13:00:00Z").getTime() / (1000 * 3600)

  let total = roundDown(end - start);
// it returns 1.5 
// I want it converted to 1hr 30min
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take the value after the decimal point and multiplay that by 60

```js
function roundDown(floating) {
    var rounded = Math.round(floating * 100) / 100;
    return rounded;
}

const start = new Date("2020-12-03T11:30:00Z").getTime() / (1000 * 3600);
const end = new Date("2020-12-03T13:00:00Z").getTime() / (1000 * 3600)


let total = roundDown(end - start);


//just add these lines of code
const remaining = total - Math.floor(total);
const minutes = 60 * remaining;
console.log("Minutes : " + Math.round(minutes) + "\tHours : " + Math.floor(total));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is simple string operation:

`const totalTime = total.getHours().toString() + " : " + total.getMinutes().toString()`

Comment: total is number, you can't call method `getHours` on a number

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert 1.5h to 1h30min, you just have to multiply the decimal part by 60 (e.g. 0.5*60 = 30). I'm not really sure if I understood you question though.

Answer (score 0):

```
function roundDown(floating) {
         var rounded = Math.round(floating * 100) / 100;
         return rounded;
}
const start = new Date("2020-12-03T11:30:00Z").getTime() / (1000 * 3600);
const end = new Date("2020-12-03T13:00:00Z").getTime() / (1000 * 3600)

  let total = roundDown(end - start);
console.log(total)

    var hour = Math.floor(total);
    var decimal = total - hour;

    var min = 1 / 60;
    // Round to nearest minute
    decimal = min * Math.round(decimal / min);

    var minute = Math.floor(decimal * 60);
    console.log(minute)
```